Congrats to sfdcfox
I just wanted to express my congratulations to Brian for breaking the 500000 reputation points level, reflecting just how much he helps the Salesforce community. Truly inspiring!

Even if I ask dumb questions he always makes a respectful response to guide me where I need to be. Truly a humble legend
